# flowing objects on top of fixed positioning elements

Tags: css, positioning, z-index, fixed, element

I see a new fad with websites is elements scroll down the page and disappear behind other elements(say for example a large image disappears behind a white background with text on it.) and I am trying to achieve a similar effect where one image which is fixed positioned scrolls **behind** other elements. The problem I am having is that z-index has no effect on fixed positioned elements because they are out of the normal flow. Is there a css way to position fixed elements behind other elements?

Comment: I haven't found how to position elements over a fixed element yet, however I have found that if you set the image as a background of the parent div, and set the (background-attachment: fixed;) it makes for a fine secondary option.

Answer (score 3):

One thing you can do is set the `z-index` of that element to `-1`. However, I believe you have to put a `position:relative;` on all the things ontop of it since if I remember correctly some browsers ignore the `z-index` for elements that have `position:static;`. Also, have you considered simply setting that image as the background image of the page with css? 
**UPDATE**

Since I don't know the exact nature of your code, I can suggest a basic mockup of how you can accomplish this: 
**Fiddle:**http://jsfiddle.net/jatN2/ 
**CSS**

```
#bg {
    position:fixed;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    z-index:-1;
}
#wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    background:transparent;
}
body {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background:transparent;
}
.content {
    padding:20px;
    background:#FFF;
    margin:0px;
    display:block;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<img src="<!--Your background image here -->" id="bg" />
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="space"><!--Just a placeholder for the area where you want the background image to show. Give this element a height so it'll show the bg for that amount of height --></div>
    <div class="content">
        <!--Put your content here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah but now evertime the window resizes the div's get thrown off. I cannot keep the background image from moving out from the div in front of it.

Comment: I've updated my post with sample code that you can work with :)